# dependency is packaged with provided scope in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-dependency

I want to package the spring boot jar without the javafaker dependency. I am using the Javafaker dependency and want it to be loaded only during dev time.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Even after adding the scope as `provided`, the jar is packaged as part of the final jar file. How can I exclude the dependency in the final build.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this is done intentionally by the Spring Boot team

From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/413 :

*The packaging of provided scoped jars is intentional. The reason for this is that many developers are used to adding things like servlet-api as provided. Since there won’t be a servlet container to actually “provide” the dependency we package it inside the JAR.*

The only way to ensure that it doesn't end up in your JAR file is to use the spring boot maven plugin configuration and exclude it there.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: "Since there won’t be a servlet container to actually “provide” the dependency we package it inside the JAR" - IMO, Phil Webb was wrong there: tomcat-embed jar does contain servlet-api, jetty doesn't, however that would be more elegant to ask eclipse developers to publish embeddable artifact as well.